# Qt : what is the difference between layout and widget?

Tags: user-interface, qt, qt4

I thought that layout is just a widget that keeps more widgets inside.
But now I find that I can't add it to other widgets using addWidget.
For instance how to add a layout to QSplitter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[QWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html) has built in support for layouts through the [`layout()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#layout) and [`setLayout(...)`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#setLayout) functions.  The layout object controls the positioning of different child widgets that may be added to the layout.  In addition, it makes sure to correctly size its parent widget based on the [constraints](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum) specified.  If the layout does not yet have a parent widget, then as soon as the layout is attached to a widget with `setLayout()`, it will set the size of that parent widget.

But, some widgets are more like a layout manager than a widget, such as [QSplitter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsplitter.html) and [QTabWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtabwidget.html).  Consider, for example, QSplitter.  Although a single widget, it presents two different areas that may be worked with.  In this case, a single layout manager for two different areas doesn't really make sense.  Like QSplitter, QTabWidget has some behaviors which make a single layout not only unnecessary but not useful.

I think it's the above melding of layout and widget that makes the separation of layout and widget sometimes confusing.

Comment: If you use the language of Model-view-controller design pattern. Is it correct to say that the "layout" is the controller? or can you not relate this to "model-view-controller" design pattern?

Comment: Ancient question, but no, the layout is part of the view in an MVC design pattern. The purpose is to decouple the Model(s), View(s) and Controller(s). It is quite possible to change the layout without any change to the Model or Controller (imagine changing a list of items from a horizontal layout to a vertical layout, for example). The View, however, would necessarily change. The layout is part of the View.

Answer (score 4):

No, a layout is not a widget or a container. A layout is more like a "helper" that's attached to a window and figures out the best place to put each widget.

This example from the Qt docs should help (http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.2/layout.html):

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget;
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
QPushButton *button4 = new QPushButton("Four");
QPushButton *button5 = new QPushButton("Five");

QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(button1);
layout->addWidget(button2);
layout->addWidget(button3);
layout->addWidget(button4);
layout->addWidget(button5);

window->setLayout(layout);
window->show();
```

Answer (score 4):

`QLayout`s are layout managers. They manage the positioning and resizing of widgets inside a parent widget. From the docs:

> Layouts are an elegant and flexible way to automatically arrange child widgets within their container. Each widget reports its size requirements to the layout through the sizeHint and sizePolicy properties, and the layout distributes the available space accordingly.

For example, setting the layout of a widget to `QHBoxLayout` will result in its child widgets being laid out horizontally.

You can read more about it [here](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/layout.html).