# Difference between android:widgetLayout and android:layout for preference?

Tags: android, xml, layout, preference

I'm getting some weird configuration where widgetLayout configures the inner space of a list item and layout configures the whole item list and the screen background? Can someone actually explain what is the widgetLayout?

Comment: check this link i think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609078/qt-what-is-the-difference-between-layout-and-widget

Answer (score 2):

`android:layout`: The layout for the entire Preference (include title, summary and widget)

`android:widgetLayout`: The layout for the controllable widget portion of a Preference (e.g. a checkbox preference would specify a custom layout consisting of just the CheckBox here)

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/override-layout-of-android-preference/

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `layout` defines the whole `preference` row where as the `widgetLayout` defines only the part usually contains a control (e.g. switch, checkbox, seekbar, dropdown...). Therefore you're free to define either the whole row or only the widget if the default preferences don't serve you.

Answer (score -2):

> android:widgetLayout

The layout for the controllable widget portion of a Preference. This is inflated into the layout for a Preference and should be used more frequently than the layout attribute. For example, a checkbox preference would specify a custom layout (consisting of just the CheckBox) here.

[Check this link for more Explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)

Comment: the reason i asked on stack overflow is because i did not understand the documentation. what is the "controllable widget portion"?