# Custom preference layout hight

Tags: android

I'am using this layout to use it as a widgetLayout to my checkBoxPreference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/abc_btn_checkbox_aimen"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="SubTitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my prefs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="General"
    android:key="category_key">
    <Preference
        android:key="lang"
        android:title="Language" />
    <Preference
        android:key="theme"
        android:title="Theme" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="cbnbs"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/checkbox_layout_a_ar_1" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="cbnbs_big"
        android:title="Title"
        android:summary="SubTitle" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And the result is as in the attached picture: [image]

So, how to make the custom preference layout (the orange one) **hight** the same as the default one? and how to maintain and make the Title and subTitle **text size** a little **smaller** and **bolded** like the default?
Also, how to keep the same **alignment** and **padding** of two preferences?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111910/difference-between-androidwidgetlayout-and-androidlayout-for-preference) I realized that my mistake was in the line

```
android:widgetLayout="@layout/checkbox_layout_a_ar_1"
```

Once I replaced with:

```
android:layout="@layout/checkbox_layout_a_ar_1"
```

the preference **hight** is perfect now. But just one thing, how to make the title and subTitle the same font type and appearance as the default one?